# QUIZ app ... UIAlertController not coming up and not restarting back to initial question

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

**The nextQuestion() and the startOver() function I believe is where it is giving me trouble... when I go through the questions it get to the end and does not pop up the alert on the screen just have to hit the True or false one and then it will startOver() but then it skips the first one and goes directly to the second question**

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
//Place your instance variables here
let allQuestions = QuestionBank()
var pickedAnswer : Bool = false
var questionNumber : Int = 0

@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var progressBar: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let firstQuestion = allQuestions.list[0]
    questionLabel.text = firstQuestion.questionText
    //when app loads it will display the first question in the array of question bank
}


@IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if sender.tag == 1 {
        pickedAnswer = true
    }
    else if sender.tag == 2 {
        pickedAnswer = false
    }
    //above - will change the picked answer based on which tag # is pressed
    checkAnswer()

    questionNumber = questionNumber + 1

    nextQuestion()

}


func updateUI() {

}


func nextQuestion() {

    if questionNumber <= 12 {
    questionLabel.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].questionText
        //if the current questionNumber is equal to or less than 12 then it will change the display text to the current question
    }
    else {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Congrats!", message: "Do you want to restart?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: { UIAlertAction in
            self.startOver()
        })

        alert.addAction(restartAction)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
}


func checkAnswer() {

    let correctAnswer = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].answer

    if correctAnswer == pickedAnswer {
        print("You got it!")
    }
    else {
        print("Wrong!")
    }
}


func startOver() {
    questionNumber = 0
    nextQuestion()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

its a firmware issues. just updated to the latest IOS 13 update and the simulator ran the app no issues so I believe it is with my firmware being the latest versus Xcode with the previous one. it ran no issues on the simulator. simulator on 13.1.1 and I just uploaded to 13.1.3 that's the only difference. I had looked at the completed app from the course and its all line for line the same except the firmware.[app running on Xcode simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMpdB.png)